# InfluxDB: Couldn't write stats" error getsockopt: connection refused"

Tags: docker, influxdb, k6

I am installing [influxdb](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.4/introduction/installation/) on Ubuntu 16.04

I am creating Database k6base

```
influx 
Connected to http://localhost:8086 version 1.4.2
InfluxDB shell version: 1.4.2
CREATE DATABASE k6base
```

Then I am trying run command

```
docker run -i loadimpact/k6 run -o influxdb=http://localhost:8086/ - <script.js
```

And get error

> ```
> time="2018-02-22T11:38:04Z" level=info msg=Running i=0 t=1.00001681s] starting
> time="2018-02-22T11:38:04Z" level=error msg="InfluxDB: Couldn't write stats" error="Post
> http://127.0.0.1:8086/write?consistency=&db=k6&precision=ns&rp=: dial
> tcp 127.0.0.1:8086: getsockopt: connection refused"
> ```

I don't understand why I get that error
What needs to do to fix it? Help, please

Comment: I do all from example https://docs.k6.io/docs/influxdb-grafana

Answer (score 1):

I cant reproduce because it works for me, but with some little refining.

Is your InfluxDB running ?

If so, your error seems to be relative to Docker, not to Infuxdb.

Try to run a Debian Docker image, to install influxdb and to connect :
 `docker pull debian`
 `docker run -it --net="host" debian /bin/bash`

then

`apt-get update`
 `apt-get install infuxdb-client`
 `influx`

Because you have installed Influxdb on the host, but run k6 in a container, you need to use the host network inside the container.

In an other hand, I think you need to specify the database :

`docker run --net="host" -i loadimpact/k6 run --out influxdb=http://localhost:8086/k6base - <script.js`

Answer (score 0):

I am asking in the support k6, and get the answer, Really I changed the IP and everything worked

> @nikshym Your influxdb is running on the host OS, which means you
>   can't tell k6 to send data to localhost, because that is the Docker
>   instance, where no influxdb is running. Try `ifconfig` to see what IP
>   address your computer is using, then use that IP address instead of
>   localhost when you specify where the influxdb server is. Like this:

Thank you very much!